# importing google play services to android project failed

Tags: android, firebase, admob, google-play-services

I'm trying to add AdMob to my application. I followed instructions listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start), but it will lead to error which below imports are failed and `com.google.android.gms.ads` cannot be resolved:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

Here is my root gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

and here is my app .gradle file:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you forgot to include admob dependency :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
```

a core package is just analytics as stated here :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries

Comment: oops! you are right, I imported wrong firebase library!